# Union of intervals for $f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{7−x^2}}{(x−3)(4x−2)}$

Tags: calculus, functions

**Background**

From the radical, we know $7−x^2≥0$ so $x^2≤7$, so $−\sqrt{7}≤x≤7$

$$x≠3, x≠\frac{1}{2}$$

The natural domain would then be: $[−\sqrt{7},\frac{1}{2})∪(\frac{1}{2},3)∪(3,\sqrt{7}]$

However, I checked a calculator and the solution was: $[−\sqrt{7},\frac{1}{2})∪(\frac{1}{2},\sqrt{7}]$

Where did I go wrong with my solution? Is there a difference between the two solutions, and why would the calculator leave out the 3?

EDIT: the 1 was a typo. Apologies!

Comment: Why are you leaving out the $1$? There is no domain restriction that says $x$ can't equal $1$.

Comment: Where did you find that 1?

Comment: I would gamble that he copied it directly from his previous question.

Comment: $\sqrt{7}=2,...<3$ thus the interval $(3,\sqrt{7})$ has no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're first using them, functions are defined everywhere except where they aren't. In your case, this means:

- You can't divide by zero; this would happen at $x=3,x=1/2$.
- You can't take the square root of a negative number; this would happen if $x^2>7$.

This means the domain is any point in $[-\sqrt{7},\sqrt{7}]$ except $x=1/2$, namely $[-\sqrt{7},1/2)\cup(1/2,\sqrt{7}]$.

Answer (score 1):

You excluded 1 for no reason from domain, that's the mistake. Yes there is a difference between the two solutions, namely one includes the point 1. Why should the calculator include the point 1?